# How do I translate clip planes in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, clipping

So the short of it is that I'm trying to switch from old openGL's glClipPlane function to gl_ClipDistance[0].

For glClipPlane I could intuitively do (pseudocode)

```
pushMatrix()
glRotatef(camera.xRot, 1,0,0)
glRotatef(camera.yRot + 180, 0,1,0)
glTranslate(x-camera.x, y-camera.y, z-camera.z)

glClipPlane(plane_equation)
popMatrix()
```

and this would translate the plane to the correct location, and face it in the right direction.

For the life of me I cannot get the plane to translate with GLSL - I've tried passing various model matrices, model/view matrices, and altering the plane equation, but no matter what I do the plane is attached to the "Camera" instead of being attached to the "object". As in, moving the camera also moves the portion of the object being clipped, which is less than ideal.

Here are some things I've tried in my vertex shader based on random google searches:

```
vec4 modelPos  = ModelMat * vec4( Position, 1.0 );
gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(Position, 1.0);
gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(modelPos,uClipPlane);
```

or:

```
// vec4 modelPos  = ModelMat * vec4( Position, 1.0 );
gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(Position, 1.0);
gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(gl_Position,uClipPlane);
```

or:

```
vec4 modelPos  = ModelMat * vec4( Position, 1.0 );
gl_Position = ProjMat * ModelViewMat * vec4(Position, 1.0);
gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(uClipPlane, ModelMat);
```

Is it just that I don't understand how to properly calculate the model matrix? or is there some obvious plane translation step that I'm missing that could solve my problems?

Comment: "For the life of me I cannot get the plane to translate with GLSL - I've tried passing various model matrices, model/view matrices, and altering the plane equation, but no matter what I do the plane is attached to the "Camera" instead of being attached to the object." Well, if you want a clip plane in object space, than you have to apply it to the object space position directly.

Comment: @derhass since posting this I also tried 
`gl_ClipDistance[0] = dot(vec4(Position, 1.0),uClipPlane);` After thinking about it I figured this would make the most sense - yet it still seems to move with the camera. Is this not object space?

Comment: Thank you for the help btw - this actually helped me solve my problem as I looked into it more and realized that Position was being transformed before being handed off to the shader. Transforming the clip plane with the same matrix makes the plane happen in object space. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, that's an interesting concept with your transformed object space, and something nobody could have guessed from the information given in the question...

Comment: @derhass yes, this is for a minecraft mod, so i couldnt have guessed it either.. thanks for the help again.